# Jenkinsfile How to sort a map of maps by a certain field

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In jenkinsfile I need to sort a map of maps resulting from a readJSON by a certain value, in this example the `BuildOrder` field.

I looked at groovy examples but those do not seem to work in jenkinsfile.

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        json = readJSON file: '', text: '{ "repos": [ { "Name": "repo2", "Url": "ssh://host/repo2.git", "BuildOrder": 0}, { "Name": "repo1", "Url": "ssh://host/repo1.git", "BuildOrder": 1} ] }'

        println "json obj is ${json}"               
        json.repos.sort().each { myRepo -> 
            println "myRepo ${myRepo} ${myRepo.Name}"
            myRepo.each { myProperties -> println "myProperties ${myProperties}" }
        }
    }
}
```

works but it sorts by repo, if I change this to

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        json = readJSON file: '', text: '{ "repos": [ { "Name": "repo2", "Url": "ssh://host/repo2.git", "BuildOrder": 0}, { "Name": "repo1", "Url": "ssh://host/repo1.git", "BuildOrder": 1} ] }'

        println "json obj is ${json}"               
        json.repos.sort(){it.BuildOrder}.each { myRepo -> 
            println "myRepo ${myRepo} ${myRepo.Name}"
            myRepo.each { myProperties -> println "myProperties ${myProperties}" }
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Preparation)
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
json obj is [repos:[[Name:repo2, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:0], [Name:repo1, Url:ssh://host/repo1.git, BuildOrder:1]]]
expected to call net.sf.json.JSONArray.sort but wound up catching org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2.call; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: d0dc08ff-f1f0-4e76-819f-27e7068774a6
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such field found: field java.lang.Integer Name
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:402)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:386)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:7)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2125)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:1980)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:73)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:65)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by moving the sort to a separate method marked with `@NonCPS`.

Following yields the result I want.

```
@NonCPS
def sortrepos(map) {
    return map.sort(){it.BuildOrder}
}

node {
    def mvnHome
    stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
        json = readJSON file: '', text: '{ "repos": [ { "Name": "repo3", "Url": "ssh://host/repo2.git", "BuildOrder": 5},  { "Name": "repo2", "Url": "ssh://host/repo2.git", "BuildOrder": 0}, { "Name": "repo1", "Url": "ssh://host/repo1.git", "BuildOrder": 1} ] }'
        println "The json obj is ${json}"

        repos = sortrepos(json.repos)
        println "The repos obj is ${repos}"
        repos.each { myRepo -> 
            println "myRepo ${myRepo} ${myRepo.Name}"
            myRepo.each { myProperties -> println "myProperties ${myProperties}" }
        }
    }
}
```

results in

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Preparation)
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
The json obj is [repos:[[Name:repo3, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:5], [Name:repo2, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:0], [Name:repo1, Url:ssh://host/repo1.git, BuildOrder:1]]]
[Pipeline] echo
The repos obj is [[Name:repo2, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:0], [Name:repo1, Url:ssh://host/repo1.git, BuildOrder:1], [Name:repo3, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:5]]
[Pipeline] echo
myRepo [Name:repo2, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:0] repo2
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties Name=repo2
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties Url=ssh://host/repo2.git
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties BuildOrder=0
[Pipeline] echo
myRepo [Name:repo1, Url:ssh://host/repo1.git, BuildOrder:1] repo1
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties Name=repo1
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties Url=ssh://host/repo1.git
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties BuildOrder=1
[Pipeline] echo
myRepo [Name:repo3, Url:ssh://host/repo2.git, BuildOrder:5] repo3
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties Name=repo3
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties Url=ssh://host/repo2.git
[Pipeline] echo
myProperties BuildOrder=5
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```